# DMA7th 1.1 Propositional Logic - Exercise 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Which of these are propositions? What are the truth values of those that are propositions?

a) Do not pass go.

b) What time is it?

c) There are no black flies in Maine.

d) 4 + x = 5.

e) The moon is made of green cheese.

f ) 2 n ≥ 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logic, a proposition is a contextual declarative statement that is either true or false, but never both.

> a) Do not pass go.

Is **NOT** a proposition;

> b) What time is it?

Is **NOT** a proposition;

> c) There are no black flies in Maine.

Is a proposition; with the truth value False.

> d) 4 + x = 5.

Is **NOT** a proposition; as its truth value **Unknown**.

> e) The moon is made of green cheese.

Is a proposition; with the truth value False.

> f ) 2 n ≥ 100.

Is **NOT** a proposition; as its truth value **Unknown**.